# Run appium scripts without using Eclipse or any IDE

Tags: automated-testing, testng, appium

I developed appium scripts for my Android app in Eclipse and using this IDE to execute. But I wonder there's any way to run appium scripts on other PC without installing Eclipse or any IDE. I also integrated TestNG and run by TestNG.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your project to Maven project and use the surefire plugin. Inside the plugin mention the testng.xml file as the test suite. Now you can run your scripts in any environment using below commands.

1. mvn install - This will install all the dependencies
2. mvn test - This will run your scripts

   ```
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
       <configuration>
         <suiteXmlFiles>
           <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
         </suiteXmlFiles>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
   ```

Reference: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

Comment: Tried your way but it display error:  No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Comment: you have to install maven first

Comment: Maven was installed! But error is still existing

Comment: Sorry you should install JDK in the target system. Java JRE is for running application and doesn't contains compiler . Please install JDK also (JDK contains JRE + compiler)

Comment: JDK 13 was installed but error still existing

Comment: @phongtran https://www.guru99.com/maven-jenkins-with-selenium-complete-tutorial.html follow these steps

Answer (score 0):

@PDHide
Tried your way but it display error
[image]

I also changed the path to installed JDK on my PC
[image]